# Timeout for requests.post not working in Python

Tags: python, request, python-requests, timeout

I have a python script using requests.post :

```py
try:
    r = request.post(url, json=data, timeout=10)
except requests.Timeout:
    print("timeout")
```

(I have also tried with `except Timeout:` and `except requests.exceptions.Timeout`)

This code should print "Timeout" after around 10 seconds if the server is down, right?

However, it doesn't. My script is waiting indefinitely, like if timeout was `None`

Do you know why?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the whole code:

```py
import requests
from twisted.internet import task, reactor
import json
import sys
import os\

timeout = 30 # 30 sec timeout to loop PostParam

url = os.getenv('URL',"http://127.0.0.1:5000")

def PostParams():
    # Subscribe to MQTT Broker
    data = subscribing_broker()

    # Iterate in the JSON payload to get the different units
    for unit in data: 

            try:
                # Make the POST request - data as JSON - blocking call - timeout 10s
                req_result = requests.post(url, json=unit, timeout=10)

                # Get the answer in json
                pred = req_result.json()

                # Publish to MQTT
                publishing_broker(pred, pub_topic )

            # Connection timeout, continue
            except Timeout:
                print("Connection timed out, passing")
                pass


# Infinite loop - Timeout is 30 sec
loop = task.LoopingCall(PostParams)
loop.start(timeout)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Depends how much data the server is sending you. You've not said whether `request.post` actually fails. `timeout` only applies to failed attempts to make a connection.

Comment: My server is down for this test. So it should reach the timeout, no?

Comment: Then something else is going on. Presumably _something_ has acknowledged the request

Comment: How about you `print(r.status_code)`

Comment: How can I print it ? The request is blocking, so it won't go to this instruction. And it doesn't go in the except case since it's waiting in the try

Comment: Can you share your whole code? That makes it easier for us to reproduce the error and try to fix it.

Comment: See my edit with the code

Comment: What is `url` here? I mean from `url = os.getenv('URL',"http://127.0.0.1:5000")`. I'm stabbing in the dark, even with your code, but something is wonky here

Comment: What do you mean? I can put directly `url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000"` it doesn't change anything. For dev the server is running localy on my PC, but it will be somewhere else in the future, that's why i'm using env variable

Comment: I meant that it could be pulling a value for `url` from the environment that you weren't expecting. At this point, I'm out of ideas sorry

Comment: Ok correct, I just checked the URL env variable and it's not defined. I was a good idea but not the right one..Thanks anyway